# Atualizar campos do CCK do Drupal 6 através de outra ferramenta

Tags: php, drupal

Estou querendo atualizar os campos do CCK do Drupal 6 através de um mini painel onde alguns determinados usuários poderão alterar somente as suas informações.

Estou optando por atualizar fora por ser uma área que os clientes já conhecem e não ter que mudar de ambiente, no caso o Drupal, que é usado internamente pela equipe para cadastro de algumas coisas.

Achei uma solução atualizando diretamente no banco de dados, mas, não estão me aconselhando, alguma sugestão de uma maneira mais correta?

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho certeza absoluta se você quer permitir que alguns usuários alterem somente alguns nodes específicos ou campos em todos os nodes de um determinado tipo.

Caso a ideia seja permitir que eles editem somente certos nodes o módulo [ACL](https://www.drupal.org/project/acl) pode resolver seu problema.

Caso a ideia seja permitir que eles editem alguns campos CCK em um tipo de conteúdo, a opção mais simples é usar o módulo [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) que permite a criação de permissões para cada campo. Dá trabalho definir todas as permissões, mas você vai ganhar mais controle sobre seus formulários.

Se nenhuma destas opções atender sua necessidade, você pode pensar em criar um novo tipo de conteúdo (digamos, o "altera_dados") contendo somente os campos que estes novos usuários poderão usar. Depois cria regras usando o módulo [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) que alteram os campos em questão do node original quando um conteúdo do tipo "altera_dados" for salvo. Considere utilizar a função **args()** para pegar parâmetros necessários a partir da URL.

Por fim, a forma mais robusta é [criar um módulo customizado](http://ndvo.blog.br/pt-br/drupal/como-criar-um-m%C3%B3dulo-para-seu-site-drupal/). Neste módulo, criar um [formulário customizado](http://www.ndvo.blog.br/pt-br/drupal/formulario-customizado/) que altera somente os campos desejados dos nodes em questão. Neste caso você vai precisar usar o **hook_menu** para criar a página do formulário e usar o **drupal_get_form** como "page callback" e o nome da função que constrói o formulário como "page arguments". Na função definida como 'submit' de seu formulário utilize utilize o **hook_node_save** para alterar os campos a partir dos valores fornecidos no formulário.